# Criação de documento de stock na V10

Tags: vb.net

Boa tarde,

estou a tentar criar um documento de stock no evento Depois de Gravar no Editor de Vendas, mas não estou a conseguir declarar os objetos...

```
Dim objDocStock As InvBEDocumentoStock
Dim objLinhaDocStock As InvBELinhaDocumentoStock
```

Quais são as referências que tenho de importar? Já tentei tudo e mais alguma coisa... No VBA era a GCPBE900, portanto aqui deveria ser a INVBE100, certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da v9 para a v10 ocorreram bastantes mudanças, principalmente ao nível dos inventários. Sugiro que procures documentação que te mostre essas mudanças, também podes usar este artigo para te orientares: https://developers.primaverabss.com/v10/como-migrar-projetos-v10/

Os documentos de stock passaram para os documentos internos, apenas ficaram no inventário as transferências e as composições.

A referência que tens que adicionar é esta: IntBE100.

Terás que ter algo assim:

```
Dim objDocStock As IntBE100.IntBEDocumentoInterno
Dim objLinhaDocStock As IntBE100.IntBELinhaDocumentoInterno
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era mesmo isto!